# OpenWRT: Cant install packages - memory issue

Tags: router, openwrt

I switched from default firmware to OpenWrt for my: **TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND v1** and have the problem that I am **not able to install any new packages**.

**What I did:**

- Flash OpenWrt
- Installed Luci (no problem there)

And than when I try to install anything else I get:

```
Collected errors:
* xsystem: wget: vfork: Out of memory.
 * opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci/luci-app-wshaper_git-15.338.68695-3bae3c7-1_all.ipk, wget returned -1.
 * opkg_install_pkg: Failed to download luci-app-wshaper. Perhaps you need to run 'opkg update'?
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package luci-app-wshaper.
```

The important thing seems to be : *** xsystem: wget: vfork: Out of memory.** And yep I did try reboot and 'update' several times.

**But under Luci -> Software I can see:**

[image]

**And here is my DF output:**

```
root@OpenWrt:~# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 2048      2048         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    14052      1128     12924   8% /tmp
/dev/mtdblock3            4736       936      3800  20% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay        4736       936      3800  20% /
tmpfs                      512         0       512   0% /dev
root@OpenWrt:~#
```

**OpenWRT Router Link:** https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd

**Manufacturer Link:** http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WR1043ND_V1.html

Please does anyone have any idea what could cause the issue? I know the solution could be using an external USB but I want to aviod this at all costs + I cannot imagine that this router would have space just for luci :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go into /etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf and comment out everything but base and luci, the first two.

No idea why, but opkg started using tons of RAM with all of those enabled, which they are by default.

Comment: Remember to mark your own answer as answered to keep it all tidy.

Comment: This works for other packages as well, keep `base` and `another package`. Then update and install, working perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a `/etc/opkg` directory at all in OpenWRT 12.09.

Comment: I just commented out reboot_routing and reboot_telephony and it worked! Thank you

Comment: On a TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND v1 with 18.06.0 above trick works like a charm. (On the 1043ND v2 the error doesn't even show.) Bug appears RAM related, there is [a related bug report at the OpenWrt bug tracker](https://bugs.openwrt.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=1144).

Comment: On my TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v4 with openwrt-19.07 this trick also helped.

Comment: Would be great an explanation about how/why this work and the usefulness of at least core and kmods. The usual list is: core kmods base luci packages routing telephony

Answer (score 0):

Thats my distfeeds. At first try have some troubles with install **udpxy**, after comment some points in conf, all works.

```
$ cat /etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf

src/gz designated_driver_base http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/base
#src/gz designated_driver_kernel http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/kernel
#src/gz designated_driver_telephony http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/telephony
src/gz designated_driver_packages http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/packages
#src/gz designated_driver_routing http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/routing
src/gz designated_driver_luci http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/luci
src/gz designated_driver_management http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/management
# src/gz designated_driver_targets http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/packages/targets
```